# function FIND_IN_SET() not working in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

The function `FIND_IN_SET()` works on local but not working on the server.when I load  `company_by_category_model` by calling  controller(controller name) then it throws an error

#### Error:

```
FUNCTION firstdial.FIND_IN_SET does not exist

SELECT * FROM (`company_information`, `user_information`) 
WHERE `FIND_IN_SET` ('16',company_category) 
AND company_information.allowstatus=1 
AND company_information.delstatus=0 
AND company_information.user_id=user_information.user_id 
ORDER BY `company_id` desc

Filename: C:\wamp\www\firstdial\system\database\DB_driver.php
Line Number: 331
```

#### Code:

```
function company_by_category_model($category_id)
{   
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('company_information,user_information');
    $search="FIND_IN_SET ('$category_id',company_category) 
        AND company_information.allowstatus=1 
        AND company_information.delstatus=0 
        AND company_information.user_id=user_information.user_id";
    $this->db->where($search);
    $this->db->order_by('company_id','desc');
    $query=$this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must always check the results from the FIND_IN_SET() function somehow to make it work, try this:

```
  $this->db->where("FIND_IN_SET('$value',employer_job_location) !=", 0);
```

Comment: thnks buddy your answer is very helpful for me

Comment: You are welcome. and if you find the answer helpful then please approve the answer so that other can also get benefited from this Q/A.

Answer (score 2):

```
function company_by_category_model($category_id)
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('company_information,user_information');
    $search="FIND_IN_SET ('".$category_id."',company_category) 
        AND company_information.allowstatus=1 
        AND company_information.delstatus=0 
        AND company_information.user_id=user_information.user_id";
    $this->db->where($search);
    $this->db->order_by('company_id','desc');
    $query=$this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```

Try removing single quote from `$category_id` this is variable

Answer (score 0):

`FIND_IN_SET()` - this function is useful where you have comma separated list of values stored in database and want to check if a value exist in that comma separated list.

Example: `WHERE FIND_IN_SET( ‘yellow’, color list )`